# DB2 ODBC: Receiving error when creating System DSN in 32-bit ODBC administration

Tags: db2, odbc

Up until 2 days ago, I was using a System DSN in the 32-bit ODBC Administration setup to connect to my DB2 database.  I was having no issues.  Suddenly it started giving me an error

> "SQL10007N Message '-1005' could not be retrieved.  Reason code '5'"

.  I've attempted to delete the data source and recreate it, but I continue to get the same error.

For the record I can still connect to the DB in Data Studio and run queries against it.   I just can't create the data source because of this error.

I've verified the following info is correct:
- Database name
- Database alias
- Host name
- Port number

Yet I still receive the same error.  Has anyone seen this?

Comment: Is this a server or client host, where you create this DSN? If it's a client, then what's the db2 client package used?

Comment: It's a client, and I installed the IBM Data Server Client 11.1.  We're at DB2 v.11.1.4.4 Fix Pack 4.  Upgrading to Fix Pack 5 isn't an option.  We have several client machines that can still connect using the same setup - there's something specific about my PC.

Comment: Data Studio uses jdbc driver, not the ODBC/CLI.  that's why you can connect from it. 
Any error logged on windows event logs ?  I suspect your client install got corrupted some how. Maybe a new windows update. or AV playing a role..

Comment: [SQL10007N](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic21.html#sql10007n) RC=5 means problem with locale/codepage. Try `db2set DB2CODEPAGE=1208` or investigate what happens with your OS default codepage.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein When you mentioned locale, it reminded me that I had changed a locale setting troubleshooting an unrelated issue.  I went to Region->Administrative->Change System Locale and checked "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support".  That was the only recent change that had been made.  I went back and unchecked it and my ODBC worked like a charm.